# ASP.NET, thread and connection-string stored in Session

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, session, connection-string

My application can connect with multiple data bases (every data base have the same schema), I store the current DB, selected by user, in Session and encapsule access using a static property like:

```
public class DataBase
{
    public static string CurrentDB
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentDB"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentDB"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Other pieces of code access the static CurrentDB to determine what DB use.

Some actions start background process in a thread and it need access the CurrentDB to do some stuff. I'm thinking using something like this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static string _threadSafeCurrentDB;

public static string CurrentDB
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return _threadSafeCurrentDB;
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentDB"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            _threadSafeCurrentDB = value;
        else
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentDB"] = value;
    }
}
```

And start thread like:

```
public class MyThread
{
    private string _currentDB;
    private thread _thread;

    public MyThread (string currentDB)
    {
        _currentDB = currentDB;
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    }

    public DoWork ()
    {
        DataBase.CurrentDB = _currentDB;

        ... //Do the work
    }
}
```

This is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think you should be able to determine which thread uses which database, so I would create a `class` inherited from `Thread`, but aware of the database it uses. It should have a `getDB()` method, so, if you need a `new Thread` which will use the same database as used in another specific `Thread`, you can use it. You should be able to `setDB(db)` of a `Thread` as well.

In the session you are using a current DB approach, which assumes that there is a single current DB. If this assumption describes the truth, then you can leave it as it is and update it whenever a new current DB is being used. If you have to use several databases in the same time, then you might want to have a `Dictionary` of databases, where the `Value` would be the DB and the `Key` would be some kind of code which would have a sematic meaning which you could use to be able to determine which instance is needed where.

Comment: I like the inherited class from Thread, you suggest me. I'm using a single current DB.

Comment: @alvarogonzalez, then you might want to use that class inherited from Thread, so you can get/set db settings real-time, while your current DB is singular. If my answer helped you to determine which practice suits you best, then you might consider accepting it.